# Training a model with only averages of ground truth labels

Tags: regression, missing-data, supervised-learning

I have a large dataset of feature vectors, and I want to predict some value from them using either linear regression or a neural network. I do not have ground truth labels for each sample separately, but I do have ground truth for label averages of groups of 100 samples. For each sample, I know which group it belongs to and the average label of that group.

What is the best way to train on this type of dataset? Should I average the feature vectors of each group, so that every averaged sample has a label? Or should I train on the individual samples, and assume that all samples within a group have the same label (the average label)?

Does the answer to this question depend on whether I am using linear regression or a neural network? Is there a different model for prediction more suitable for this case?

Comment: May I ask what an example application is?

Comment: @aesthete Say you have lots of information of every person in a city - age, gender, marital status, house size, criminal record, and so on. You want to predict their income, but you do not have ground truth income per person in your dataset, you only have the average income for every neighborhood in the city.